# gzip with file descriptor

Tags: python, python-2.7, file-io, gzip

I need to be able to open a gzipped CSV file using a file descriptor. When I do the following (this is simplified code that still trigger the error):

```
file_path = r"E39O6KS6J8MIZW.00.0f6db4e5.gz"
fd = os.open(file_path, os.O_RDONLY, os.O_BINARY)
# ...
file_object = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=io.FileIO(fd, mode='rb'))
reader = csv.reader(io.BufferedReader(file_object))
for row in reader:
    print row
```

I get a CRC check error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./log_processing_scripts/dev.py", line 40, in <module>
    post()
  File "./log_processing_scripts/dev.py", line 36, in post
    for row in reader:
  File "C:\Python27\lib\gzip.py", line 252, in read
    self._read(readsize)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\gzip.py", line 299, in _read
    self._read_eof()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\gzip.py", line 338, in _read_eof
    hex(self.crc)))
IOError: CRC check failed 0x4b77635f != 0xbe13716L
```

The file is not(!) corrupted, I can process it just file with gzip.open(file_path).

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The O_RDONLY and O_BINARY flags should be or'd together, like so:

```
fd = os.open(file_path, os.O_RDONLY | os.O_BINARY)
```

Reference: https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#open-constants

Comment: Ah, crap!  Knew this was something really stupid.  Thanks.

Comment: well spotted, upvoted. Looking at the help of GzipFile I noticed `fileobj, which can be a regular file, a StringIO object, or any other object which simulates a file` so I thought maybe the low-level file descriptor (an int) returned by `os.open` would not match/work

Comment: @Pynchia: that's why I'm wrapping the fd in FileIO

Comment: yes, of course, sorry. You can also use `os.fdopen`